# Version Control for Unix and Linux Scripting

Tags: version-control

I work for a company that uses Unix and Linux servers.  Often times, scripts (in shell, perl, or python) are written, then modified multiple times, which can generate confusion.

I was tasked with researching and implementing a version-control system on these servers to help us to better handle script writing and editing.

Any suggestions on what version-control solution to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any one out of Git, Mercurial, and Bazaar should be fine.  These are popular modern distributed version control systems, but even if you don't particularly think you need a DVCS, they are the top contenders.  If you are scared of DVCS concepts for some reason, you might also want to consider Subversion, but it should not be your first choice unless you have reasons to want to stay in the previous decade.

Any version control is better than no version control.  You will be wondering how you ever got by without it within a few weeks.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control